# Data from other user not visible

Tags: oracle, permissions, users

I am using Oracle and SQL Developer to create a database. I am fairly new to SQL, so this may be a simple question. I have my SYSTEM user, who owns several tables, for example this one:

```
CREATE TABLE T_SCHEDULE
(
    sched_id number(4) NOT NULL,
    master_id varchar2(5) REFERENCES T_MASTER(master_id) ON DELETE CASCADE NOT NULL,
    client_id varchar2(5) REFERENCES T_CLIENT(client_id) ON DELETE CASCADE NOT NULL,
    box_num number(5) REFERENCES T_BOX(box_num) ON DELETE CASCADE NOT NULL,
    car_num varchar2(10) REFERENCES T_CAR(car_num) ON DELETE CASCADE NOT NULL,
    price number(7),
    job_start timestamp NOT NULL,
    job_stop timestamp NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(sched_id)
);
INSERT INTO T_SCHEDULE VALUES (4001, 'M1001', 'C2002', 3002, 'Р232ХВ', 9000, TIMESTAMP '2021-10-02 12:30:00.0', TIMESTAMP '2021-10-02 17:30:00.0');
INSERT INTO T_SCHEDULE VALUES (4002, 'M1002', 'C2003', 3003, 'А847КР', 4000, TIMESTAMP '2021-10-02 08:15:00.0', TIMESTAMP '2021-10-02 12:15:00.0');
INSERT INTO T_SCHEDULE VALUES (4003, 'M1003', 'C2004', 3005, 'С966ЕС', 25000, TIMESTAMP '2021-10-02 10:45:00.0', TIMESTAMP '2021-10-02 13:45:00.0');
INSERT INTO T_SCHEDULE VALUES (4004, 'M1004', 'C2005', 3001, 'Т138УВ', 30000, TIMESTAMP '2021-10-02 10:30:00.0', TIMESTAMP '2021-10-02 15:30:00.0');
INSERT INTO T_SCHEDULE VALUES (4005, 'M1005', 'C2006', 3006, 'Р364ВЕ', 20000, TIMESTAMP '2021-10-02 09:00:00.0', TIMESTAMP '2021-10-02 11:00:00.0');
INSERT INTO T_SCHEDULE VALUES (4006, 'M1001', 'C2007', 3005, 'О117УУ', 24000, TIMESTAMP '2021-10-03 14:10:00.0', TIMESTAMP '2021-10-03 17:10:00.0');
INSERT INTO T_SCHEDULE VALUES (4007, 'M1002', 'C2008', 3002, 'Н439АМ', 6000, TIMESTAMP '2021-10-03 10:40:00.0', TIMESTAMP '2021-10-03 15:40:00.0');
INSERT INTO T_SCHEDULE VALUES (4008, 'M1003', 'C2009', 3003, 'О896МТ', 8000, TIMESTAMP '2021-10-02 14:30:00.0', TIMESTAMP '2021-10-02 18:30:00.0');
INSERT INTO T_SCHEDULE VALUES (4009, 'M1004', 'C2010', 3004, 'Т694КС', 12000, TIMESTAMP '2021-10-03 09:50:00.0', TIMESTAMP '2021-10-03 17:50:00.0');
INSERT INTO T_SCHEDULE VALUES (4010, 'M1005', 'C2001', 3001, 'У601КК', 22000, TIMESTAMP '2021-10-02 16:00:00.0', TIMESTAMP '2021-10-02 20:00:00.0');
```

I also have user m1001 with this permissions:

```
GRANT INSERT(sched_id, master_id, client_id, box_num, car_num, job_start, job_stop) 
    ON T_SCHEDULE TO m1001;
GRANT SELECT ON T_SCHEDULE TO m1001;
```

When I inserted a row in m1001's workspace:

```
INSERT INTO SYSTEM.T_SCHEDULE 
    (sched_id, master_id, client_id, box_num, car_num, job_start, job_stop) 
VALUES 
    (4011, 'M1001', 'C2001', 3001, 'У601КК', TIMESTAMP '2021-10-04 16:00:00.0', TIMESTAMP '2021-10-04 20:00:00.0');
```

it was successful. I can now view it with select query:

```
SELECT * FROM SYSTEM.T_SCHEDULE;
```

[image]

However, when I run this same query in SYSTEM user workspace I see the old version of the table:
[image]

Why is that and how can I make m1001's data visible?

Comment: I'm not an Oracle guy, but maybe you should prefix your `CREATE TABLE T_SCHEDULE` with SYSTEM too. (CREATE TABLE SYSTEM.T_SCHEDULE)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I have my SYSTEM user, who owns several tables

**Do not** use any pre-defined usernames that come with the database itself.
You have *no idea* what Oracle might choose to do there in the future, and if Oracle were to introduce a SYSTEM-owned table with the name as *yours*, then either *your application* or the *database itself* would be in a lot of trouble.

Create *your own* [Tablespace and] User Account and put your tables, etc., in that.

> When I inserted a row in m1001's workspace ... it was successful. I can now view it with select query ...  However, when I run this same query in SYSTEM user workspace I see the old version of the table

And the Magic Word is - COMMIT.

Oracle absolutely, totally, definitively WILL NOT allow one User to read *uncommitted* changes made by another User.  Our Friends in Redwood City have spent *millions* building a database architecture that *guarantees* this.